# Access GridView ItemTemplate control ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using ASP.NET GridView on ASPX page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GrdLimitAndUtilization" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None"
                    Width="99%" meta:resourcekey="GrdAccountListResource1" OnRowDataBound="GrdLimitAndUtilization_RowDataBound"
                    ShowHeader="True" rowstyle-cssclass="rowHover" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="gridView">
                    <Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Excess" meta:resourcekey="Excess">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="120px" CssClass="gridheader" />
                            <HeaderTemplate> <asp:Label ID="col5a" Text="Excess" runat="server"></asp:Label></HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkExcess" runat="server" value='' Text='<%# Bind("Excess") %>'
                                    meta:resourcekey="HyperLink1Resource1"></asp:HyperLink>
                                <asp:Label ID="Excess_Currency" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Currency") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width="120px" HorizontalAlign="Left" CssClass="customerProductItemTemp gridviewLeftMargin" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I know I can access GridView column by following code:

```
GrdLimitAndUtilization.Rows[0].Cells[0].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
```

BUT, How can I access value/text of only HyperLink control with ID="lnkExcess"??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [RowDataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) event like this:-

```
protected void GrdLimitAndUtilization_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HyperLink lnkExcess = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("lnkExcess");
        //Access hyperlink's properties here.
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! very simple solution :)